# Specific sorting of linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have to sort my linked list in specific way for example I have such linked list: 3->1->4->1->7->5->7 it has to be sorted like that: 7->1->7->1->3->4->5. So from what I understand I have to find for example max element in list and add it at beginning and delete such element from current list, I'm curious if is there any way to for example swap place of element in middle of list to beginning of list. Or I have to delete such element and allocate memory with given data and add it at beginning? Overall it's task from programming class test and has to be done using singly linked lists.

Comment: I still have no clue what the logic behind the sort is.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please give specific details.

Comment: You can swap elements only in a doubly linked list, since even if you swap the pointers of the nodes that's needed to be swapped, you're running the previous nodes's `->next`. What you *can* do, is swap the `data` of the nodes.

Comment: Well this is something similar to task I have been given on test I had to sort numbers in such way that it was max,min,max,min,rest of numbers. I'm trying to figure out how to do it. So the only way to do it is to delete min/max element found from list and add it to start set it to new head and still keep somewhere old head of list?

Comment: It would be pretty helpful if you'd quote the task itself. You need to sort numbers? Why did you choose a linked list for the drill? Are you allowed to use a doubly linked list? Can you write a generic function (something like `qsort()` of standard algorithm) that will make the needed swaps of nodes or data (according to need and ability) and you'll just provide him with a comparison algorithm.

Comment: @Quaker : if the linked list is free from loop, you may swap elements without copying data if you keep trace of the `previous` elements. This is easy if you iterate on the list. Putting an element at start is also easy : you just need to store the pointer to the beginning somewhere and return it in the end.

Comment: @Quaker: You can swap elements in a singly-linked list if you keep pointers to previous node pointers when walking the list, including the head node. You only need doubly linked lists if all you have is node pointers and not the source of the pointers.

Comment: @francis and @M Oehm are correct, my bad.

Comment: An easy way would be to transform to an array in linear time, sort it using any existing sort algorithm and then build up the final list, again linear time. Very efficient and simple and no need to swap elements in a linked list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach: given an *unsorted* list `P`:

1. Create a list `Q`.
2. Append `max(P)` to `Q`.
3. Remove `max(P)` from `P`.
4. Append `min(P)` to `Q`.
5. Remove `min(P)` from `P`.
6. Repeat steps 2 through 5 one more time.
7. Sort `P` in ascending order.
8. Append `P` to `Q`.

`Q` is now your *sorted* list.

This approach assumes `P`'s length is no less than 4.

Comment: This will work I think as I'm working on premade list of numbers given in task which is no less than 8, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap nodes in singly-linked lists if you have pointers to the list's node pointers, i.e the `head` pointer and the nodes' `next` pointers. You can do that because you have to walk the list anyway to find the maximum. (Be careful to chose the last maximum, otherwise subseqnet calls to this function will alwas bring the same `7` to the front.)

```
void max_to_front(struct node **head)
{
    struct node **mp = head;    // current max pointer address
    struct node **pv = head;    // iterator pointer address
    struct node *nd = *head;    // iterator pointer
    int mx;

    // nothing to do for empty or single-node lists
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->next == NULL) return;

    // find maximum
    mx = nd->value;
    while (nd) {
        if (nd->value >= mx) {
            mp = pv;
            mx = nd->value;
        }
        pv = &nd->next;
        nd = nd->next;
    }

    // move max to the front, i.e.  update the pointers
    nd = *mp;
    *mp = (*mp)->next;
    nd->next = *head;
    *head = nd;
}
```

Note how `pv` always contains the address of the node pointer via which you have come to the current node, `nd`, so you can update it; `mp` is just the pointer address for the node with the maximum value.